# Javascript - Check if field exists inside text/template script

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a script of type `text/template` in which I display some values retrieved from an ElasticSearch database. My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="script1">
    <div style="color:black;"><%= highlight.field1 %></div>
</script>
```

However, there are times when this highlight value is not defined and I would like to display `_source.field1` instead. My initial guess was to add a try catch, but that wouldn't work:

```
<script type="text/template" id="script1">
    <div style="color:black;"><%= try{ highlight.field1 } catch(e) { _source.field1 } %></div>
</script>
```

Later edit: highlight is not always going to be available. Instead the _source field is always available.

In addition, I am using `backbone.js`, and inside `views.js` I have defined:

```
    DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({  
        tagName : "div",  
        className: "document well",
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
            },
        template: [_.template($("#script1").html())],
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template[0](this.model.toJSON())); 
            return this;
        }
     });
```

The model is:

```
{
  "_index": "index1",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "id1",
  "_score": 10.139895,
  "_source": {
    "field1": "fieldValue1"
  },
  "highlight": {
    "field1": [
      "highlightedFieldValue1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What does "wouldn't work" mean? What does the data that you're giving the template look like?

Comment: I get an error when the script is interpreted saying "Unexpected token try".

Comment: I get the same problem if I try to use an if statement, "Unexpected token if"

Comment: But what does the data look like? Are `highlight` and `_source` always going to be available?

Comment: highlight is not always going to be available. Instead the _source field is always available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in our case try..catch is overhead, you can use [logical expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

```
  <script type="text/template" id="script1">
    <div style="color:black;">
      <% if (typeof highlight !== 'undefined' && highlight.field1) { %>
        <%= highlight.field1.length ? highlight.field1[0] : highlight.field1  %>
      <% } else if (typeof _source !== 'undefined' && _source.field1) { %>
        <%= _source.field1 %>
      <% } %>
    </div>  
  </script>
```